# Navigation Bar - Height/Spacing issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get Navigation Bar to look like this:

[image]

I couldnt get it work properly, how to fix it?

```
<ul class="subnav">
    <li> <a href=""> Text One</a></li>
    <li> <a href=""> Text Two</a></li>
    <li> <a class="active" href=""> Text Three</a></li>
    <li> <a href=""> Text Four</a></li>
</ul>

<style>
    .subnav {
        list-style:none;
        border-bottom:1px solid #c7c4ba;
    }
    .subnav li{
        display:inline;
        font-size:14px;
        margin-right:1px;
    }
    .subnav a:hover {
        background-color:white;
        color:black;
    }

    .subnav  a { 
        background-color:#c7c4ba;
        color:white; 
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .subnav .active {
        background-color:white;
        color:#c61c25;
        border:1px solid #c7c4ba;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PQyL7/1/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/ypZqK/1/  The effects you wanted are there but I don't know how else you want different events to appear.

CSS:

```
.subnav {
        list-style:none;
        border-bottom:1px solid #c7c4ba;
        float:left;
    }
    .subnav li{
        display:inline;
        font-size:14px;
        margin-right:1px;
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        height: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        border:1px solid #c7c4ba;
        border-bottom: 0;
        line-height: 25px;
        background-color:#c7c4ba;
    }
    .subnav li:first-child{
        margin-left: 25px;
}
    .subnav a:hover {
        background-color:white;
        color:black;
    }

    .subnav  a { 
        color:white; 
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .subnav li.active {
        background-color:white;
        z-index:999;
    }

    .subnav li.active a{
        color:#c61c25;
}
    .clearBorder {
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: white;
        float: left;
        height: 1px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="subnav">
    <li> <a href=""> Text One</a></li>
    <li> <a href=""> Text Two</a></li>
    <li class="active"> <a href=""> Text Three <span class="clearBorder"</span></a></li>
    <li> <a href=""> Text Four</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This answer is the best so far -- it satisfies all of: (1) small gap between tabs, (2) line at the bottom (3) no line at the bottom of the active tab.

Comment: To the OP, I would recommending altering the hover selector with other elements unless you only want the anchor background to change color on hover instead of the tab (li). Unless you want to keep it that way.

Comment: Thanks for code.. The background should should be white instead of link background when I hover.. How to fix this?

Comment: Yep like this but I dont want <span> tag, must be a way to tweak CSS? Also when I hover any link bottom border should be white.,

Comment: You sure are asking for a lot. I'm not sure how to fulfill your request without the assistance of javascript. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ul class="subnav">
    <li><a href="">Text One</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Text Two</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="">Text Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Text Four</a></li>
</ul>

<style>
    .subnav {
            list-style:none;
            padding:4px;
            border-bottom:1px solid #c7c4ba;
    }
    .subnav li{
            display:inline;
            font-size:14px;
    }
    .subnav a:hover {
            background-color:white;
            color:black;
    }

    .subnav  a { 
            background-color:#cccccc;
            color:white; 
            text-decoration: none;
            padding:4px;
    }

    .subnav .active {
            background-color:white;
            color:#c61c25;
            border-left:1px solid #c7c4ba;
            border-right:1px solid #c7c4ba;
            border-top:1px solid #c7c4ba;
            border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
```

http://htmledit.squarefree.com/